# Explicitly refer to member variable to remove "Local declaration of ... hides instance variable" warning

Tags: objective-c

I have this segment of code:

```
- (void)setTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    tableView = tableView;
}
```

Now, I understand why I'm getting the warning. But shouldn't this *fix* it?

```
- (void)setTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    self->tableView = tableView;
}
```

I'm aware I can change the argument name or the ivar name, but *i don't want to*. In C++ for example, one can use `this->foo = foo`, and java one can use `this.foo = foo`. Python can use `self.foo = foo`. What's the equivalent in objc? (And no, I don't want to use `@property`'s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the parameter's name is shadowing the ivar's name even on the right-hand side of the assignment. While you and I know you mean to assign the parameter's value to the ivar, the compiler can't be certain, so it warns you.

Change the name of the parameter and the warning will go away.

Comment: As I said, I _understand_ that, but shouldn't the `self->` fix it? If not, what's a way to fix it, _without renaming the ivar or the param's name_? Again, as I said, this is possible in a lot of other languages, and I'm expecting (er -- hoping) that it's possible in objc as well.

Comment: *There is no other way to fix the warning* without turning off warnings, which you shouldn't do. The fix is to rename the parameter, and *that's it*.

Comment: The issue is not the left-hand side of the assignment, where you added `self->`. It's now the *right-hand* side, where `self->` is still missing (as you intended). The compiler doesn't know for certain what you mean, so it's warning you that the action it's taking might not match your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You may want to add the explanation in the comment to your answer, as it clarified the issue for me. Also - do you have a official source you could point me to that says there's no way to disambiguate an ivar from an arg? Thanks again!

Comment: It's just basic logic. If two things are named `foo`, and I say I want to access `foo`, which one do I mean?